# Timeout error while uploading to large file in adls

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake

I need to upload a **200 mb** file to **adls** using python.

I'm using the code provided in the official documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python?tabs=azure-ad

While calling the following function for upload -

```
def upload_file_to_directory_bulk():
    try:

        file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="system")

        directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("my-directory")
        
        file_client = directory_client.get_file_client("uploaded-file.txt")

        local_file = open("C:\\file-to-upload.txt",'r')

        file_contents = local_file.read()

        file_client.upload_data(file_contents, overwrite=True)

    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
```

It works for small files

I get the error - `('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out'))` when I try to upload larger files like 200 mb.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be related to the upload speed. Try increasing the timeout to 60 seconds. Also if you split the file in chunks a separate connection(*with separate timeout*) will be created for each chunk.

```
file_client.upload_data(file_contents, overwrite=True, timeout=60)
```

With chunk size:

```
file_client.upload_data(file_contents, overwrite=True, timeout=30, chunk_size=25)
```

Comment: what is the chunk size in this case - 25 bytes or 25 mb?

Comment: These are megabytes

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the timeout value and chunk size in your code while uploading large data.

```py
default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format("https", storage_account_name), credential=default_credential)
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="<container-name>")
directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("<directory>")
file_client = directory_client.get_file_client("uploaded-file.txt")

local_file = open("<file.txt>",'r')
file_contents = local_file.read()
file_client.upload_data(file_contents, overwrite=True, timeout=60, chunk_size=250)
```

Comment: I think you miss the chunk_size parameter in the example.